# Unable to return to JDBC SQL query results after executing a subquery

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

I am working on a scenario where I have to execute a SQL query in JDBC to find the information about students enrolled in a particular subject. When this query runs, 3 records should display at a time. Then user is prompted to either press Enter to go back to main menu or press B to continue browsing the results or enter StudentID to pull results from previous semesters. In my code below, after displaying 3 results, my code works correctly when user presses Enter or B. However, after StudentID is entered and sub-query is run, the code automatically displays the main menu. I would like it to return back and continue displaying the remaining results just like option B to browse.

Below is the code snippet:

```
// Below is the SQL query that will be executed
// This snippet is part of loop where all different subjects are entered into an array and then user selects one subject
String displayStudent = "select * from students where subject = '" + subjectArray[choice - 1] + "'";
ResultSet displayThisList = stmt.executeQuery(displayStudent);
while (displayThisList.next()) {
    System.out.println("Fname: " + displayThisList.getString(2));
    System.out.println("Lname: " + displayThisList.getString(3));
    System.out.println("StudentID: " + displayThisList.getString(1));
    System.out.println("Grade: " + displayThisList.getString(4));
    System.out.println("Subject: " + displayThisList.getString(5));
    System.out.println();
    subCount++;
    if ((subCount % 3 == 0)) {
        String response = readEntry("Enter StudentID to view last semester results or\nB Enter to browse or \nENTER to go back:");
        System.out.println();
        if (response.equals("")) {
            // Back to member menu
            break;
        } else if (response.equals("B")) {
            // Continue to browse
            continue;
        } else {
            // Check if the StudentID is valid or not
            int checkID = 0;
            String queryID = "select * from students where StudentID='" + response + "'";
            ResultSet setID = stmt.executeQuery(queryID);
            while (setID.next()) {
                String FName = setID.getString(2);
                String LName = setID.getString(3);
                String Grade = setID.getString(4);
                String Subject = setID.getString(5);
                checkID++;
                System.out.println("Correct ID was entered");
                //Code to execute query based on above info from a different table
            }
            if (checkID == 0) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Invalid ID. Please enter again.");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: corrected the typo error

Comment: Do you change the `displayThisList` variable in the "Code to execute query etc..."?

Comment: No, i dont. Lets say that when user enters the student ID, it only displays "Correct ID was entered" and then should return back to the remaining results. I added this print statement below statement: checkID++

Comment: You are using quotes in studentId also. Is your studentId field varchar type ? `where StudentID='" + response + "'`

Comment: Try debugging your code and you will find the reason problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the same `Statement` object for different queries **if** you use the corresponding `ResultSet` interchangeably. Create one statement for the "outer" query and another one for subquery.

Secondly, in `while`-loop (`setId.next()`) you probably read data from wrong `ResultSet` (should `setID.getString()`, not `setISBN.getString()`).

Besides, if SQL queries are generated basing on user input, you definitely should use `PreparedStatement` instead. Consider what is going to happen, when someone enters `StudentId` as:

```
'; delete from students; select * from students where StudentID='foobar
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion on creating separate statements and using PreparedStatement. I have to be away now but I will try this in the evening and update you. Thanks.

Comment: Confirmed that code works with the suggestions provided above. Thanks for your inputs